# Changing keypad settings

Tags: opensuse, keyboard, gnome3

When I setup my Ubuntu machine, I had the option to configure the keypad style in the gnome control panel.

I used to check the setting that enables windows-like behavior (Shift+Keypad does not toggle NumLock. It helps me use Shift+Home\End) from the following window:[image]

Yesterday I installed openSuse 13.3 (Gnome 3), and I couldn't find a similar setting.